# Why can't I use same instance to save details in database using JPA repository?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistent

I'm new to java and working on a java spring project. Now I've to make sure my data is being stored in database, I'm inserting some values manually to test this part.

The code looks like this:

```
Department departmentDetails = new Department();
departmentDetails.setDepartmentName( "cse" );
departmentDetails.setStatus( 1 );
departmentDetails.setModifiedBy( "mehul" );
departmentDetails.setCreatedBy( "mehul" );
departmentDetails.setCreatedOn( new Timestamp( System.currentTimeMillis() ) );
departmentDetails.setModifiedOn( new Timestamp( System.currentTimeMillis() ) );

departmentDetailsRepository.save( departmentDetails );

departmentDetails.setDepartmentName( "ECe" );
departmentDetails.setStatus( 1 );
departmentDetails.setModifiedBy( "xyz" );
departmentDetails.setCreatedBy( "xyz" );
departmentDetails.setCreatedOn( new Timestamp( System.currentTimeMillis() ) );
departmentDetails.setModifiedOn( new Timestamp( System.currentTimeMillis() ) );

departmentDetails = departmentDetailsRepository.save( departmentDetails );
```

Instead of creating new object, I'm using it again after saving its details (by calling `departmentDetailsRepository.save( departmentDetails );`) in the database.
But when i execute this, only the second details, i.e department *ECE* created by
*xyz* is saved, but not the first record.

I am using spring data's jpa repository as follows:

```
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {}
```

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: There is no object overriding here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Hibernate actually trigerring save operation not after calling `save` method, it persist your data during commit of transaction. Also if you using the same object it will just update it, you even don't need to call `save` second time. To create 2 records in db you should create new object because your current object is in persistent state.

Comment: You said, " not after calling save method,  " . Then when exactly is that saved?

Comment: Calling the `save` method just chenges the state of object to persistent, by default request to data base will sent when transaction commit is trigered, also you can call `flush` method to sent request to db if you need this for some reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new instance in order to create "new" row.

Answer (score 0):

You are using it the wrong way.

Try this

```
Department departmentDetails = new Department();
...    
departmentDetailsRepository.save(departmentDetails);

departmentDetails = new Department();  //Create a new object.
...    
departmentDetails = departmentDetailsRepository.save(departmentDetails);
```